# adding editable CheckBoxField to gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, user-controls

I am trying programatically add a check box column to a grid view.  This grid view has multiple other columns but I only want the check box column to be editable.  The only examples I have seen require that I add an "Edit" link to each row.  I would like for the check box column to be editable by default, without the need for a link.  The check box should also support autopost backs.  Anyone have any suggestions?  Below is what I have so far:

```
    Dim gv As New GridView

    With gv
        .ID = "gridViewFoundUsers"
        .AutoGenerateColumns = False
        .DataKeyNames = New String() {"UserId"}
        .GridLines = GridLines.Both
        .AllowSorting = True
        .AllowPaging = True
        .PageSize = numRows
        .Width = tableWidth
        .BorderColor = Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#808080")
        .AutoGenerateEditButton = True

        .HeaderStyle.CssClass = foundUserHeadStyle
        .RowStyle.CssClass = foundUserEvenRows
        .Columns.Clear()

        Dim UserIdTF As New BoundField
        With UserIdTF
            .DataField = "UserId"
            .HeaderText = "UserID"
            .SortExpression = "UserId"
            .ItemStyle.Wrap = True
            .ItemStyle.Width = 100
        End With

        Dim DomainTF As New BoundField
        With DomainTF
            .HeaderText = "Domain"
            .DataField = "Domain"
            .SortExpression = "Domain"
            .ItemStyle.Wrap = False
            .HeaderStyle.Font.Underline = False
        End With

        Dim SelectUserTF As New CheckBoxField
        With SelectUserTF
            .HeaderText = "Select User"
            .ItemStyle.Wrap = False
            .DataField = "isSelected"
        End With

        .Columns.Add(UserIdTF)
        .Columns.Add(DomainTF)            
        .Columns.Add(SelectUserTF)
     End With
```

The gridview is part of a composite server control, so there is no client side code pages.

Thanks!